# linearly dependence of the coordinates of eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in \text{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{Q})$. Suppose the characteristic polynomial of $A$, $C_{A}(x)$, is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$. Define $L: \mathbb{C}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{n}: L(X) = AX$. Assume the eigenvalues of $L$ are simple. Prove that coordinates of every eigenvector are linearly dependent over the rationals.

The minimal polynomial $m_{A}(x) = m_{L}(x)$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{C}$ and since the eigenvalues of $L$ (and hence of $A$) are simple (algebraic multiplicity 1), the linear factors are distinct. So that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{C}$. Now since $C_{A}(x)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$, there exists an irreducible factor $q(x)$, a polynomial with rational coefficients. Letting $W = \ker q(A)$. Then $W$ is $A$-invariant so that the restriction of $A$ to $W$ is diagonalizable. This approach has hit the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method**
We try, for every $i,$ to find a non-zero matrix with rational coefficients such that it multiplies the eigenvector $v_i$ to give $0.$

---

Let $\lambda_i, i=1,\cdots, n$ be eigenvalues of $L.$ So $C_A(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n(x-\lambda_i).$ And without loss of generality we suppose that $C_A(x)=\prod\limits_{i=1}^m(x-\lambda_i)\prod\limits_{i=m+1}^n(x-\lambda_i)=f(x)g(x)$ for $f,g\in\mathbb Q[x]$ and $m\gt1.$
Moreover, on the eigenspace $E_{\lambda_i},$ the fact that $m_A(A)|_{E_{\lambda_i}}=0$ implies that $(x-\lambda_i)$ divides $m_A(x)$ for every $i.$ Thus $m_A(x)=C_A(x).$
Therefore, both $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ are not $0.$ As a consequence, both $f(A)$ and $g(A)$ belong to $\mathbb Q[x]$ and, $\forall i=1,\cdots ,n,$ either $f(A)v_i=0$ or $g(A)v_i=0.$ This means that the coordinates of $\lambda_i$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb Q.$
$\square$
Hope this helps, and inform me of any errors or inappropriate points so that I can improve upon them, thanks.

Comment: This suffices. The fact that $C_{A}(x)$ splits completely into linear factors and its roots are distinct (as they are eigenvalues that are simple) implies that $C_{A}(x) = m_{A}(x) $, which implies that $A$ does not annihilate any proper factor of $m_{A}(x) =C_{A}(x) = f(x)g(x)$. If there exists an eigenvector $v_{j}$ such that $f(A)v_{j} \neq 0$ and $g(A)v_{j} \neq 0$, then $f(\lambda_{j})v_{j} \neq 0$ and $g(\lambda_{j})v_{j} \neq 0$. So, $f(\lambda_{j})g(\lambda_{j}) \neq 0$, a contradiction. wlog: $\sum_{j=1}^{n}C_{j}x_{ji} = f(A)v_{i} =0$ for all $i$, where $C_{j}$ are columns of $f(A)$.

Comment: I think in the last sentence you intended to write $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nC_{kj}x_{ji}=0, \forall k, i,$ where $v_i=(x_{ji})$ and $f(A)=(C_{kj}).$ And yes, you got the point. :)

Comment: Thank you. That would work too, but I simply intended $C_{j}$ to be the columns of $f(A)$ and not the entries of $f(A)$.